# Set AVCaptureDevice format range

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I am able to query and find formats for slo-mo at 240FPS. There are two, with `420v` and `420f` each, at Full HD (correct me if I'm wrong that they only differ in the pixel value range). I was wondering if I could distinguish them at runtime.

```
print(format.formatDescription.mediaSubType) // this prints "420v" and "420f" each
```

This does not work, however:

```
    // always false
if format.formatDescription.mediaSubType == .init(string: "420f") {
    // ...
}
```

A workaround I have been adapting is to rely on the for-loop to always find `v` first then `f` for my device, but I am not sure if this is guaranteed for all devices.

---

Here are some of discovered slow motion formats on this iPad:
(other slo-mo formats are for 1280x720 dimension, etc.)

```
<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x280b58ec0 'vide'/'420v' 1920x1080, { 2-240 fps}, fov:64.717, binned, supports vis, max zoom:67.50 (upscales @1.00), AF System:1, ISO:18.0-720.0, SS:0.000016-0.500000> <CMVideoFormatDescription 0x2807d95c0 [0x1ff615860]> {
    mediaType:'vide' 
    mediaSubType:'420v' 
    mediaSpecific: {
        codecType: '420v'       dimensions: 1920 x 1080 
    } 
    extensions: {(null)}
}
<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x280b58eb0 'vide'/'420f' 1920x1080, { 2-240 fps}, fov:64.717, binned, supports vis, max zoom:67.50 (upscales @1.00), AF System:1, ISO:18.0-720.0, SS:0.000016-0.500000, supports wide color> <CMVideoFormatDescription 0x280731770 [0x1ff615860]> {
    mediaType:'vide' 
    mediaSubType:'420f' 
    mediaSpecific: {
        codecType: '420f'       dimensions: 1920 x 1080 
    } 
    extensions: {(null)}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already some pixel type constants defined on `MediaSubType`, like `CMFormatDescription.MediaSubType.pixelFormat_422YpCbCr8_yuvs`, but sadly no 4:2:0 variants.

You can symbolically check for 420f and 420v with

```
format.formatDescription.mediaSubType == .init(rawValue: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)
```

and

```
format.formatDescription.mediaSubType == .init(rawValue: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)
```

The strange thing is your `.init(string:"420f")` works for me.

Comment: Thanks, pal. I don't know why, but upon checking again, it works to use `.init(string: "420f")`. And thank you for mentioning about initiating with raw value and a system constant!